# Convert a Recursive CTE in SQL Server to netezza

Tags: sql, recursion, migration, common-table-expression, netezza

I have a requirement like i need to convert a recursive CTE in sql server into netezza !

Will netezza even support Recursive CTE ?

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance,
Manirathinam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive CTEs are not supported in Netezza as of version 7.2.  If you can tell us what you are trying to accomplish in your particular case, we might be able to offer a workaround/rewrite.

Comment: Its like i am trying to create two CTE's

the second CTE is recursive and will have first CTE in the join.