# Running Common Table expression in netezza as a script with Update at the end of CTE

Tags: netezza

I am trying to run a CTE in script form

e.g

```
with CTE as 
(select * from sometable);
```

on running this code part alone in the I am getting the error

> ^ found "" (at char 152) expecting `SELECT' or`'('' */

Please let me know how to run this query. thanks

Comment: This question has nothing to do with *recusive CTEs*, and is therefore not an "exact duplicate" of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358821/convert-a-recursive-cte-in-sql-server-to-netezza

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you aren't doing anything with the CTE you have defined, but the syntax requires something.

Add a SELECT after the CTE clause in the parentheses and it should work fine.

```
with CTE as 
(select * from sometable)
select * from CTE;
```

Comment: I agree but instead of the Select I need an update but when I do an update I am still getting error. So please let me know how can i update the CTE after creating it. thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example of what you are trying to accomplish with the CTE and the UPDATE?  I can post an example of using a CTE with an UPDATE statement, but it would be better to understand what you are trying to accomplish